# Unable to provide custom war file path in jenkins using deploy to container plugin

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

My jenkins job is building successfully but while deploying i need to take it from the custom path. I tried various version for providing the custom path but it always gives either "No wars found. Deploy aborted" or "java.io.IOException: Expecting Ant GLOB pattern, but saw '{$jenkinsHome}\customwar\mytest.war'."

I am using Deploy to Container plugin but tried with below fileset as well but it is also giving no wars found error.

{$jenkinsHome} - replaced with absolute path of jenkins home directory

Can you guys let me know how to pick war file from custom path in jenkins deploy to container plugin.[image: Check my maven configuration]

Comment: `{$jenkisHome}` does not look ok; typo here in the question? It would be `${jenkinsHome}`, and mind it points to jenkins home directory, not the build location for a job

Comment: this is typo in the in the question.... while u can check the absoulte path given in the image attached as well